Access string resources from iOS
I've added strings to composeResources folder and I can easily access them in Android using Res.string.my_string_name
What I can't seem to find in documentation is if it's possible to directly access string resources from iOS without shared compose UI. I can manually create a method in some exported KMP object for each string, but that's not an optimal solution.
Is there a way to directly access string resources from iOS?
